# MediaCompositio.RenderToFileAsync with MediaOverlayLayer hangs in virtual machine

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, direct3d11, uwp

When running my C# Universal Windows application in Win10 on a virtual machine (Parallels VM with DirectX 11 enabled) my application appears to hang during media composition. On all other devices, the code works fine.

I can reproduce the error by adding a transparent media overlay to a video via an `IVideoCompositor` implementation that uses Direct3D 11 to render the output.

The line it hangs on is `await mediaComposition.RenderToFileAsync`. I get two progress callbacks from the `mediaComposition.Progress` event then it stalls and doesn't do anything else.

Should this code work on a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

I think the culprit is that Parallels doesn't have support for DirectX 11. It supports 9 & 10 but not 11 or 12. It's an odd way for the code to fail but I think that's the cause.

Comment: Have you ever seen it on any other, physical machine? I am having this problem on a Windows 10 machine and I can't figure out why it happens...

Comment: No, I haven't run into it yet on a physical machine. I would suspect something funny with the graphics driver or something else with the graphics card.